# read xml in javascript problem

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

hai all,

i have a problem with my code to read the xml.I have use ajax to read xml data and populate it in combobox. My problem is it only read the first data.Here is my code

my xml like this

```
 <info>
 <area>
        <code>1</code>
        <name>area1</name>
 </area>
  <area>
         <code>2</code>
         <name>area2</name>
  </area>
  </info>
```

and my javascript

```
 if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
   //get select elements
   var item = document.ProblemMaintenanceForm.elements["probArea"];
   //empty combobox
   item.options.length = 0;
   //read xml data from action file
   var test = http.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("area");
   alert(test.length);
   for ( var i=0; i < test.length; i++ ){
          var tests = test[i];
          item.options[item.options.length] = new Option(tests.getElementsByTagName("name")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,tests.getElementsByTagName("code")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);


                             }


                     }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to verify that the XML you get back is what you expect? Walk through it and see what happens. You can use IE8's developer tools, or the Firebug plugin for Firefox, to trace the execution line-by-line. Check the values of your arrays and make sure you're using the right index for each property. At a glance, it looks like childNodes[i] is incorrect.

Comment: i have step through the code and the xml is the same what i`m expected

Comment: Please use JSON instead of XML if you can, it's a much better format for this kinda stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to index it twice. Just change that line to:

```
item.options[item.options.length] = new Option(
    tests.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
    tests.getElementsByTagName("code")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
);
```

So, for clarity your above code block should look like:

```
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
  //get select elements
  var item = document.ProblemMaintenanceForm.elements["probArea"];
  //empty combobox
  item.options.length = 0;
  //read xml data from action file
  var test = http.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("area");
  alert(test.length);
  for ( var i=0; i < test.length; i++ ){
    var tests = test[i];
    item.options[item.options.length] = new Option(
        tests.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        tests.getElementsByTagName("code")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need another loop or a fixed index instead of reusing the loop index (e.g. `...("name")[i]`) in the following line:

```
    item.options[item.options.length] = new Option(
        tests.getElementsByTagName("name")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        tests.getElementsByTagName("code")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    );
```

You are looping through the element nodes using the `var i` which obviously will get incremented by one every instance of the loop. Now, if you parse any element at `i > 0` you won't be able to access the `name` tag as there is none present (at least in your example xml).